# React-native - Expo, share on twitter

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm looking for a solution to social media share on Expo. I have tried with react-native-social-share from npm but it doesn't work on Expo. Is there any way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: you have to detach to ExpoKit to use the native library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the default share solution from React Native described here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/share.html#docsNav

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/share.html

as any other solution requires you to detach your Expo project to regular project as linking is required (e.g. https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share ) - I'm not entirely sure if there is a solution that comes with all basic social shares without native code (I believe there is none)